# Converting Date to String in groovy

Tags: groovy, apache-nifi

I want   to convert `def date= new  Date()`  to  string  so that  i could make this expression `def text=data+" "+"http://hjghjghj.ge(Service) /https:jsonparces  getting data  from taxservice:Successfully received response` and  then use  text as an string  i  have tries  toString() but it  wasn't   helpful any better  ideas?

Comment: what exactly is wrong? please provide a correct code and error/problem if you have it.

Comment: can't  cast Date()  to  string

Answer (score 0):

You don't even need `toString()`, just using it in a String concatenation transforms it, but you have to use `String + Date`, not `Date + String`, just like in Java. So either use

```
def text=""+date+" "+"http://hjghjghj.ge(Service) /https:jsonparces  getting data  from taxservice:Successfully received response
```

or

```
def text=(data as String)+" "+"http://hjghjghj.ge(Service) /https:jsonparces  getting data  from taxservice:Successfully received response
```

or

```
def text=data.toString()+" "+"http://hjghjghj.ge(Service) /https:jsonparces  getting data  from taxservice:Successfully received response`
```